# How to show a static error page on invalid route in ojet

Tags: oracle, oracle-jet

How to display an error page for an Oracle Ojet application when someone hits an invalid url? If appController.js is where the main routes are defined, how to use to add the invalid hits?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
 let navData = [
   { path: '', redirect: 'dashboard' },
   { path:'404',detail: { label: '', iconClass: '' }},        
   { path: 'about', detail: { label: 'About', iconClass: 'oj-ux-ico-information-s'}} 
   {path:/.*/,redirect:404,detail:{ label: '', iconClass: '' }}
  ];
```

Comment: One drawback is detail: { label: '', iconClass: '' } is mandatory,as per the API doc it is optional but the JET parser is throwing a css error to avoid that we need to send empty value

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).